# BroadCastReceiver Force Close For Sms receive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am creating just a simple android app which will respond to received.
I am using braodcastreceiver to receive sms.
Code for activity is

```
package com.om;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class MyTest extends Activity {
  public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
      System.out.println("SMS Received");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
      registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
  }
}
```

When I run this activity on SDK 2.1 AVD and sends SMS to that port it says Force close.
Please tell me what is error in code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should definitely post a logcat and the line that makes the app crash. Did you declare your receiver in the app manifest?

Comment: As Bicou said, you need to show us the full stacktrace from the force close for us to say anything about what is happening.  This probably isn't causing it, but rather than using System.out.println you should use the Android logging system Log.d("smsReceiver", "SMS Received")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to give it the proper permission?

I believe for SMS in your manifest, you must have something like:

android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS

Comment: Wrong Permission...`RECEIVE_SMS` is the one you're looking for...and it's not likely that...since it wont throw an exception. It just wont receive the intent.

Comment: I believe it would throw an exception however; because hes trying to register a receiver without the proper permission.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Thanks for Answers
This code works fine

```
package com.om;
```

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class MyTest extends Activity {
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String msg = "SMS Received.....";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
        toast.show();

    }



}
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED =
    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   IntentFilter inf = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
    SmsReceiver sr = new SmsReceiver();
    registerReceiver(sr, inf);

}
```

}

I have given permissions correctly.
But when i tried to register broadcastreceiver in Manifest
It force closing the app,
I don't know how to give Logs, if someone please tell me.